# How do you fix "google-chrome" is not recognized in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run HTML for the first time in VS code, but when I run it, it says

> "google-chrome" is not recognized as an internal or external
> command,operable program or batch file.

A screenshot of my problem has been attached below.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: how are you running it

Comment: Ya, not sure what you're asking without more details. When you say run it do you mean like using an extension like `open in browser` or something? Where is that string "google-chrome" come into play? As it sits the question lacks details.

Comment: sryy, heres the screenshot https://imgur.com/SxOtObG

Comment: That is not how you access a website. You also haven't even saved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save that file with the name that browser can recognize, it should look something like 'filename.html'. Then you can open it with a web server application like xampp, or just open it on your file explorer.

[image: Index file showing on file explorer]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `google-chrome` is not a recognized command in Windows (it is in Linux distros).

The easiest way to make it work is saving the ".html" file with a proper name (something.html) and then use the command `cd "C:\Users\LGU BATO\Desktop\html\"  && something.html`.

An explanation of this command is:

First, it will `cd` into the directory, as listed on the screenshot. This changes the directory of the command prompt window.

It will then open the file with your default browser.